# Optimization with probabilistic variable distribution

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $u \in \mathcal{R}^n$ be a vector of decision variables. Let $C(u)$ be a function $\mathcal{R}^n \to \mathcal{R}$ that is a measure of performance of the variables. Further, it is required that the final distribution of $u$ be normal , $u  \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, for given values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. How does one impose such a constraint on the final shape/ distribution of  the design variables ?

$\underset{u}{min} \quad  C(u)  $

$   \text{S.T.} \quad   u \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$

Comment: I’m not sure this is well-posed. The decision variables $u$ aren’t random—you’re choosing them. It doesn’t seem that these deterministic values could follow a distribution.

Comment: That is true. I am choosing $u$. But I would like to regularize them so that they closely resemble a normal distribution

Comment: It's unclear what "closely resemble" means--do you have a definition in mind?

Comment: Suppose I could define some error norm between the expected distribution and the obtained distribution and constrain it to below some value ?

Comment: “Obtained distribution” isn’t obviously defined. Think carefully about what you’re defining